# Android. I have 2 Native SO libs. If I add one of them for some platform - am I forced to add another one for that platform as well?

Tags: android, arm, native, platform

I need to use 2 Native SO libs in my Android app. One of them(my app engine) I have for armeabi and armeabi-v7a. And the second one(ads etc.) is present for many platforms (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, mips, x86_64 etc.). The question is: if I add to the arm64-v8a only 1 SO - will the app fail for that platform because of lack of abother SO for that platform? It'll look like this:

```
armeabi
   a.so
   b.so
armeabi-v7a
   a.so
   b.so
arm64-v8a
   b.so
mips
   b.so
```

And so on.
Any insight into this will be appreciated

Comment: Are you planning to use the ARMv7-A version of `a.so` on ARMv8-A devices? Does the MIPS version of the app not need `a.so` at all? Anyway, to be sure of what happens you probably ought to test this on an 64-bit device like the Nexus 9. If you can't find a suitable device to test this with you might be able to use the Android emulator, since it's possible to create x86-64 AVDs (and then you should build `a.so` and `b.so` for x86, and only `b.so` for x86-64).

Comment: @Michael He can't mix a.so(32) and b.so(64) on any arch specific app right?

Comment: Your best coverage would be if you provide armeabi-v7a and not arm64-v8a without a.so(32). Since in this case v8 will run v7 program cleanly and you'll cover v7 and v8 devices.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comments. Here are some of mine: 1. I don't build those SO's they are already built. 2. If I don't have a.so (engine) for a mips platform - there's no point in having b.so there right?